# Add a popup window to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to add a popup window in this fragment but I don't know how, any help?

```
public class Info extends Fragment {

    public Info() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.kaynaklar_info, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: check this link it will help you http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/uncategorized/how-to-create-popups-in-android-2/

Comment: is there any tutorial for this? Because i am new on app developming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PopupDialog dialog = new PopupDialog(getActivity());
```